# Change where SSH looks for key files on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, git

By default, my ssh looks for private key identities in /.ssh/ when I connect.  However, this is not a valid place in a Windows system.  How can I permanently change the default place that it looks for the private key identities, so I don't need to run `ssh-add` every time I want my keys?

Note: I got SSH when I installed mysysgit, the Windows version of Git (which comes with all the ssh executables in its /bin directory).  I think it looks in this place because it expects me to use the MinGW git bash it comes with.  However, I want to work from the cmd.exe prompt so I need it to look in a valid Windows folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh` from OpenSSH normally uses `~/.ssh/`, where ~ represents your home directory. To make it work on Windows, set the `HOME` environment variable apropriately.

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%

set HOME=C:\Users\babonk
```

Comment: if I do this: `set HOME=C:\Folder1\Folder1`, then it tries to set the HOME var to `C:\Folder1Folder2`. Do you know why this would occur? it's incredibly frustrating

Comment: Dos not work on windows 10

Comment: maybe use `setx` instead of `set`. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219780/3905529

Comment: The '\' needs to be quoted.